# Clock Signal over long distance

Tags: microcontroller, signal, clock, teensy, mems

I'm building microphone array using 16 ICS-52000 MEMS microphones and I propably have problem with clock singal because of the long distance. Below is output signal of the 8 microphone I have already installed and I'm testing right now.

[image]
Signal looks almost fine, but there is noise propably caused by reflections in SCK signal

Microphones are installed on 4x4 grid with 30cm spacing between every microphone.
Below is photo of my microphone array. The clock signal SCK is marked in orange. SCK is equal to 11,3 MHz and it's connected to every microphone in daisy-chain.
[image]

I have terminated SCK at the source using 220 Ohm resistor (I've tried different resistors like 47,100 Ohm but 220 works the best).

[image]

What else can I do to improve the SCK signal over long distance? The best solution would be to shorten the wires, but I want to keep 30cm between every microphone if possible. I also know that using breadboard isn't the greatest idea too, but right now I want to make it work with configuration like this.

Answer (score 5):

An electric signal moves about 5ns per meter. If you have about 30cm between each device, that's about 5 meters. It takes a clock edge about 25ns to travel from MCU to last mic, and it takes up to 18ns max for the mic to update data output from rising clock edge, and it takes another 25ns for signal to travel back from last mic to MCU. That's minimum 50ns and maximum of 68ns for the data to arrive at MCU.

As the frequency is 11.28 MHz, the clock period is about 88ns. So when MCU sends rising edge, the falling edge where it samples the data, there is only 44ns between edges.

Therefore, the 5m wiring is too long to operate correctly at 11.28 MHz.

You can't do that long chain.

So using the breadboard here is least of the problems. The wiring is too long, and it's just random wires, instead of impedance controlled transmission lines, so the signal flight time and reflections become issues.

The wiring must be such that the cables are short enough that clock edges an WS edges reach the mics approximately at the same time, and it takes the data edge to travel back before the MCU needs to sample it and it applies to data from all mics so that if any mic is withing tolerance, the mic has time to update the data and it has enough time to fly back to MCU.

Also, please note the design guides in the mic data sheet. The mic data pin is in specs regard to time of flight and load capacitance, if the 16 mics are placed on a 30 inch PCB track. That's less than 1 meter. Likey what you want to do is impossible unless you redesign the system according to mic design guides and use buffers.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of daisy-chaining the signal you could connect it in a star fashion, a cable from each microphone to the clock source with each cable being the same length so the propagation delay is the same for all microphones.

Also, you would want to use coaxial cable or twisted pair instead of those loose wires flopping around, so that the cable impedance is constant.

And you're correct about the breadboard not being the best choice, at 11.3 MHz you're pushing the limits. With it mostly being used as a carrier for the module you might get by okay though.

Answer (score 3):

We call these things circuits because current flows in circles. One of the most important considerations for dynamic signal integrity is that every signal wire should have a return wire close to it. So, pair up each of your SCK wires with a wire connected to microphone and controller ground.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand correctly I have to twist SCK with GND wire?

Comment: @erysvh Twisting helps, yes.

Answer (score 1):

For a long line with intermediate taps, end termination (to kill the reflection) is better than simple source termination.  (This is why RS485 has 120R terminators at each end.)

Depending on the threshold levels you may need higher drive current, but you should get a cleaner signal along the way.

Note, end termination (line to ground) is instead of source termination (driver to line).

Have a look at [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-097.pdf) app note for more details on termination options

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try this. So I have to solder a resistor in series at the end of the line?

Comment: @erysvh If you have a resistor in series at the source and terminating it to ground at the end, that is a voltage divider. It is unlikely to work, but depends on the mic input voltage levels.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694584/weird-behavior-with-sck-signal-on-breadboard), with air wiring, no termination resistors, no proper grounding, it won't work.

As Justme says, even with proper wiring, it still won't work because the propagation time in the 5m of wires is too long compared to the clock period.

Solutions:

1. Keep the 5m wiring propagation delay but remove the timing constraint
2. Keep the 5m wiring propagation delay but cheat with the timing constraint
3. Keep the timing constraint but remove the 5m wiring propagation delay

**Solution 1: Keep the 5m wiring propagation delay but remove the timing constraint**

A clock generator outputs SCK and WS at the beginning of the 5m daisy-chain. This propagates through the daisy chain of microphones. At the output side, the timing of clock and data is unusable relative to the original clock that was sent, however all the signals that went through the wiring got the same propagation delay. This means they arrive at the end of the cables in sync. So if you set the TDM receiver in slave mode (SCK and WS as inputs, not outputs) it will receive the signal without violating the timing constraints.

This does not solve the problem of reflections on the data line which is used as a bus.

[image]

**Solution 2: Keep the 5m wiring propagation delay but cheat with the timing constraint**

This is the same as your current setup, with modifications:

- Proper wiring, grounding, and termination resistors
- DATA output is taken from the end of the chain

[image]

In this case the propagation delay is 25ns for 5m of wiring + 18ns max delay in the microphone, ie 43ns. An extra 25ns is not added for data to come back through all the wires to the micro, because DATA is not connected to the micro at the beginning of the chain, but at the end.

Since the max propagation delay is really borderline (43ns vs 44ns max) this will probably work until it doesn't, which will happen at the most inconvenient time.

This needs wiring to be as short as possible, so the chain of microphones becomes a loop, and no extra wires between MCU and the loop. For example if you want to put the MCU in the center you have to snake your loop of wires so it starts and ends there, not in a corner. Or you can put the MCU in a corner.

This does not solve the problem of reflections on the data line which is used as a bus.

**Solution 3: Keep the timing constraint but remove the 5m wiring propagation delay**

A PCB in the center of the square contains the following:

- 16 output Clock buffer, with source resistor
- 16 0.1" headers
- 16 to 1 data combiner

Each microphone is connected to the PCB with cable.

[image]

The idea is to buffer the clock and send it to the 16 microphones. Then the clock latency between the mainboard and all microphones is at most the length of the longest cable, not the total length of the chain. This solves the timing issue.

Now each microphone outputs WSO which is daisy chained to the next microphone's WS on the PCB, and all cables can be standard cheap ribbon with IDC connectors (8 pins: 4 signals, 3 grounds, 1 VCC). Decoupling cap between GND and VCC under each connector.

Then to avoid reflections and signal integrity issues on the data line, you need a way to combine these 16 data lines into one. You can use an AND gate and pullups, or a mux.

Or you can just connect all the data lines together... but simulation says there's too much capacitance with all these wires.

[image]

**In all cases, if possible, the TDM receiver should be set to sample data on the rising edge of clock (not the falling edge) which doubles the time available for signal propagation.**

Comment: Just one minor note, if you change the TDM interface to sample on certain clock edge, you usually cannot set both when it samples data and when it updates the WS output. You still need to make sure that WS is output correctly in relation with SCK.

Comment: Nice catch! Checking datasheet... The microphone samples WS on clock rising edge, outputs WSO on clock falling edge and outputs DATA on clock rising edge, that's coherent with the intended use as daisy chain (WSO of mic N -> WS of mic N+1). So... yeah changing the clock setting in TDM could shift by one bit... although it says WS setup time is zero so if the MCU outputs WS and clock at the same time it should be OK if there is no skew...